# Probability density function sand question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The diameter of sand grains in a special sand roof, measured in mm, can be considered as a random variable X with probability density
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
k(x-x^2) & \text{if 0≤x≤1 }  \\
\newline 0 &\text{otherwhise}
\end{cases}$$

A)
Determine the constant k so that this becomes a valid probability density

$1=k\int _0^1x-x^2dx$

$=\int _0^1xdx-\int _0^1x^2dx$

$\int _0^1xdx = \frac{1}{2} $

$\int _0^1x^2dx = \frac{1}{3}$

$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}= \frac{1}{6}$

$k = 0.16666$

B)Find the expectation $E (4X + 3)$ and the variance $V (4X + 3)$

Does anyone know how to go about these two questions? on a) I am pretty sure that I got the correct answer. on b I'm pretty much clueless...

any tips/solutions? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

No.  You dropped $k$ from the equation between step 1 an 2.  You need to keep it in the expression, so...
$$1=k(\tfrac 12-\tfrac 13)$$

Therefore $k=6$.

---

Use the rules of Linearity and Bilinearity.

$$\mathsf E(4X+3) = 4\mathsf E(X)+3\\\mathsf{Var}(4X+3)=4^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$$

Then you just need to use the definitions and integration to find the expectation and variance for $X$.